# Set notation with subscript and superscript

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

In the "The Hundred-Page Machine Learning Book", the author uses the following notation to describe the set of all labeled feature vectors.

$$\{(x_i,y_i)\}_{i=1}^N$$

What I understand:

1. $\{\ldots\}$ denotes a set
2. $x_i$ and $y_i$ are the feature vector and its label
3. $i$ starts at $1$ and runs up to $N$

What I do not understand:

1. Is this a common set notation? I did not find anything like this

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks for the kind hint!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is not uncommon, although you more often see the subscript for defining a sequence, e.g. $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$.

Alternatives, which are more usual for sets, would be
$$\{(\mathbf{x}_i,y_i)\mid 1\leq i\leq N\}\quad\text{or}\quad\{(\mathbf{x}_i,y_i): 1\leq i\leq N\}.$$
(I might write $i\in[N]$, with $[N]$ meaning $\{1,\ldots,N\}$, but I'm not sure how common this notation is outside of combinatorics.)

As for the interpunct, are you sure that's what it is? It looks to me (from the vertical height, level with the baseline of the **x**) that this expression might simply appear at the end of a sentence, with that being the sentence-ending period.

Comment: I agree with the sentence-ending period interpretation..

Comment: This notation *may* howevre mean a *family* instead of a *set*. That is, in contrast to sets, the order matters and there may even be duplicates..

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen can you provide a reference for the notation on _families_?